# How to remove the background sound of sport commentary sound clip in ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, voice-recognition, noise-reduction

I'm working on a project which needs to convert sport commentary to text. For that I have already used Microsoft system speech library. It's working fine without background noises. Can any one tell me a way of removing this background noise from the given audio file by using ffmpeg-like tool or in some other programmatic way.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/733061/reduce-background-noise-and-optimize-the-speech-from-an-audio-clip-using-ffmpeg might help.

Answer (score 1):

For better accuracy in such case it is better to use more specialized solutions like [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial).

It helps you with different things: you can configure decoder vocabulary so it will correctly recognize sport terms and expressions

You can fully use noise robust speech recognition in order to deal with background noises. External noise cleanup is actually pretty harmful for speech recognition accuracy and is not recommended. Even a simple processing algorithm like [Vuvuzella denoising with Matlab](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/06/30/vuvuzela-denoising-with-parametric-equalizers/) is better used within the decoder, not before processing.

Comment: thanks for your guidance. Can you explain more about the way with CMUSphinx with example?